# Change html template to seo-friendly version with python

Tags: python

I have html-templates for site, something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>[title]</title>
 <style type="text/css">
body, h1, h2, h3, blockquote, p, ul, ol, img { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 1em; }
 #header {
 padding: 3em;
 }
 #header h1 {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 }
 #header h1 a {
 color: #555555;
 font-size: 8em;
 line-height: 1em;
 letter-spacing: -0.1em;
 margin-left: -0.06em;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 #header p {
 color: #555555;
 padding-right: 25em;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="header">
    <h1><a href="/">[[site_title]]</a></h1>
</div>

<div id="contents">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="content text">
             <h3><a href="#[url]">[page_title]</a></h3>
             [body]
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[page_title] is the title of article, [[site_title]] is the title of all site.

My task is to do it more seo-friendly, but same-looking.

In details:

1. More seo-friendly. I mean that [[site_title]] should not be in h1-tag (I want to change h1 to some new div, like "". And page_title should be in h1).
2. New page should looks absolutely identically as old one (I mean that old styles of [[site_title]] and [page_title] should be analyzed, and new tags should have the same tags as old ones).

This is desired result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>[title]</title>

<style type="text/css">

body, h1, h2, h3, blockquote, p, ul, ol, img { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 1em; }

#header {
padding: 3em;
}

.site_title{
font-size: 1em; position: relative; margin: 0 0 1em; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

.site_title a{
color: #555555; font-size: 8em; line-height: 1em; letter-spacing: -0.1em; margin-left: -0.06em; text-decoration: none;
}

h1{
font-size: 1em; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

</style>

  </head>
  <body style="font-size: 1em; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;">
<div id="container">

<div id="header" style="padding: 3em;">
    <div class='site_title'><a href="/">[[site_title]]</a></div>
</div>

<div id="contents">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="content text">
             <h1><a href="#[url]">[page_title]</a></h1>
             [body]
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to do this? I know python, it is ideal to do everythin only with it. But any command-line utilite or online service can be used .

Comment: Check out `lxml.html` http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Comment: I made a similar project using the xml minidom parser. Very easy but you will need to parse all the tags you want to change and replace them with what you want.

Comment: Can lxml.html parse css?

Comment: "I made a similar project using the xml minidom parser" - can you show your code please?